I don't understand Mathematica's solution to $\tan(x) < \sqrt{3}$
The inequality is quite simple: $$\tan(x) < \sqrt{3}$$ I solved it by pen, and then I wanted to check with W. Mathematica because I do lack of self confidence.
I used the graphic method, drawing the unit circle and the tangent line at $x = 1$ and the "diagonal line" passing through the origin and the point $(1, \sqrt{3})$.
Since $\tan(x) = \sqrt{3}$ when $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$, I understood that the result would be
$$(-\frac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi < x < \frac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi) \cup (\frac{2\pi}{3} + 2k \pi < x < \frac{4\pi}{3} + 2 k \pi)$$
Where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I could also take just one of the two solutions, by halving the periodicity for what I understood.
Now the solution with W: Mathematica, which as usual I don't understand:
$$c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(x=\pi +2 \pi  c_1\lor -\pi +2 \pi  c_1<x<\frac{1}{3} (-2 \pi +6 \pi  c_1)\lor \frac{1}{2} (-\pi +4 \pi  c_1)<x<\frac{1}{3} (\pi +6 \pi  c_1)\lor \frac{1}{2} (\pi +4 \pi  c_1)<x<\pi +2 \pi  c_1\right)$$
How on Earth does it take $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the intervals?
EDIT: I understood my errors, but now another question: Is there a particular reason why Mathematica doesn't just write
$$\frac{\pi}{3} + 2c_1 \pi < x < \frac{4\pi}{3} \cup \frac{3\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{3}$$
that is in a more comprehensible manner?

Is the inequality $|\tan(x)| < \sqrt{3}$ ?

@Jean No, no absolute value. But... Your question may have solved part of the problem. Or it all...

$\tan(x) < 0$ in quadrants 2 and 4, so it is certainly less than $\sqrt{3}$ there, meaning you can extend the interval $(-\pi/3, \pi/3)$ down to $(-\pi/2,\pi/3)$.  Likewise with $(2\pi/3, 4\pi/3)$, you can extend that interval down to $(\pi/2, 4\pi/3)$.

Aye, I just noticed I interpreted the result (my drawing) partially wrong... Sigh. Thank you!

Is there a particular reason why Mathematica doesn't just write
$$\frac{\pi}{3} + 2c_1 \pi < x < \frac{4\pi}{3} + 2c_1 \pi \cup \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2c_1 \pi < x < \frac{\pi}{3} + 2c_1 \pi$$
that is in a more comprehensible manner?

That I have no idea.

@J.N. You could simplify it further to $-\frac{\pi}{2} + c_1\pi < x < \frac{\pi}{3} + c_1\pi$ (since $\tan(x)$ has period $\pi$).
